# Issues with install M2Crypto via the pip installer

Tags: python, pip, centos7, m2crypto

I am  trying to install M2Crypto on my CentOS 7 server but I am getting an error message where it cannot find the file 'pip-egg-info/M2Crypto.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'. Currently I am running Python Version 2.7.5 with pip version 18.

```
[root@Server tmp]# pip install m2crypto
Collecting m2crypto
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/50/7d85dc99b1c4f29eca83873d851ec29a8e484a66b31351e62e30be9db7d1/M2Crypto-0.30.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/M2Crypto.egg-info
    writing requirements to pip-egg-info/M2Crypto.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing pip-egg-info/M2Crypto.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/M2Crypto.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/M2Crypto.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/M2Crypto.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    error: No such file or directory

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-KW7GOG/m2crypto/
[root@Server tmp]#
```

I have tried updating the the pip installer, setuptools and wheel but this hasn't fixed the issue. I have installed the M2Crypto using "yum install m2crypto" but the version (I believe is 0.21) doesn't have the ciphers I need to run a script. Any assistance in troubleshooting this issue would be great.

Comment: Do you have installed all [required dependencies](https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto/blob/master/INSTALL.rst) for M2Crypto? I don't see any output from gcc and/or swig. Of course, if all fails, feel free to file a bug [upstream](https://gitlab.com/m2crypto/m2crypto/issues/new?issue%5Bassignee_id%5D=&issue%5Bmilestone_id%5D=).

Comment: Hi mcepl,

Thank you for getting back to me, I have installed the required dependencies which includes swig-2.0.10-5.el7.x86_64 and openssl-1.0.2k-12.el7.x86_64.

Comment: Hi mcepl, I have resolve the issue by doing a 'yum install python-devel openssl-devel gcc gcc-c++'. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I'm getting the following issue - Error: Unknown SWIG preprocessor directive: include_next (if this is a block of target language code, delimit it with %{ and %})
    error: command 'swig' failed with exit status 1